# Checking Subflows in Multipath TCP Connection

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed the multipath TCP connection and have 2 interfaces active in my pc. H want to see the mptcp connection working on my device. How do I check that subflows are actually created ?

I tried to connect with multipath-tcp.org and used iperf to check if infact subflows were created but I could see only a single entry in its result. I have seen the related questions, but they don't answer my question i.e. how exactly could i see the subflows in action.

Comment: I have modified my answer to add relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You must connect to a mptcp enabled server to have subflows created otherwise mptcp just falls back to normal tcp. Also, you have to configure the kernel at runtime (you can select fullmesh option) as mentioned in the official website. And, obviolusly, you must have at least 2 interfaces active.

Then tools like iptraf, ifstat can be used to monitor bandwidth in/out.
I found [this](https://devmultipathtcp.wordpress.com/2015/05/31/checking-if-mptcp-works/) to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open two CLI at Linux environment;

2) Set Wireshark on for capture your packets:

- Use option to filter TCP connections, that's make it easy to understand the TCP behavior.

3) Use first CLI to porform **iperf** as server *(iperf -s)* and the second to perform as client *(iperf -c 127.0.0.1)*

After all, you can check the subflows in the Wireshark. Further, you can explore it deeper :)